# 23 and arithmetic progression

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, primality-test

Starting at prime $23$,
$$
23 + 3 \cdot n \cdot(n+1) 
$$
is prime for $n=1$ to $21$.  Is there
a starting prime with more successes?  Does this suggest that $23$ from
$n=1$ to $1000$ would  have the most successes? If set to n=1 to 10000, would it have the most successes? Does anyone know if
extensive computer work has been done on these questions?

Comment: Things have changed since I was last here.  How do I get to see any comments?

Comment: This kind of polynomial [is conjectured](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture) to give infinitely many primes. Not quite an arithmetic progression. What is the question again?

Comment: OK, if I set n=1 to 1000 would it have more successes finding primes than any other starting prime?    If set to 10000, also the most successes at finding primes?

Comment: I trust this will aid in the understanding of this question.

Comment: Since the formula yields a composite whenever $n$ or $n+1$ is a multiple of $23$, one might expect that the fraction of primes resulting can never exceed roughly $\frac{21}{23}$

Comment: @Keith Backman The question does NOT concern how many times primes will  consecutively be produced but how many will be  produced for n=1 to 1000 or to 10000.   Has anyone tested Euler's 41 polynomial to test its efficiency?  How can the question of efficiency not be seen in what I write?  What is possible is one question (not asked) but how many are actually produced is the question I'm asking.

Comment: @J.M.Bergot All I intimated was that was that the upper limit for $n=1000$ would not exceed $\frac{21}{23}\times 1000$, and similarly for $n=10000$. The fraction is an upper limit, as there will be other instances where the formula yields composites. Nothing in my comment went to consecutive instances, so that aspect of your comment baffles me.

Comment: @Keith Blackman  Granted, there is an upper limit for the number of primes found for n=1 to 1000.  Limit is one topic but the actual count of successes in 1000 trials IS my question.  No doubt many experiments have been done to beat Euler's 41 gadget as far as consecutive successes, but has anyone found how many it finds  out of 1000 trials?  The same question applies to other polynomials showing promise of efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f_m(p)$ be the number of primes of the form $p + 3n(n+1)$ for $0 \le n \le m$.
Then $f_{1000}(23) = 442$, while $f_{1000}(103) = 472$, $f_{1000}(233) = 474$, and $f_{1000}(1663) = 479$.

I haven't tried $10000$, but again I would expect that there are some that do better than $23$.

Comment: Finally, my English has been understood.  I'm pleased that some real numbers appeared following my asking for them.  It is surprising that larger starting primes replacing my 23 do better.